# Rudin Principles of mathematical analysis p307

Tags: analysis

"For if $ A=\bigcup A^{'}_{n}$ with $A^{'}_{n} \in M_F(\mu)$, write $A_1=A^{'}_{1} $, and
$$ A_n=(A^{'}_1\cup ...\cup A^{'}_n)-(A^{'}_n \cup ... \cup A^{'}_{n-1})$$ $(n=2,3,4,...)$.

Then 
$$ A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$$
I can't understand why $A_n$ is expressed like the above? Should the correct one be 
$$ A_n=A^{'}_n-(A^{'}_1 \cup ... \cup A^{'}_{n-1})$$

Comment: The two formulas are equivalent. Rudin's choice might make more apparent what $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n$ is and consequently why $A=\bigcup\limits_nA_n$.

Comment: You mean that the following 2 are equivalent ?$$ A_n=(A^{'}_1\cup ...\cup A^{'}_n)-(A^{'}_n \cup ... \cup A^{'}_{n-1})$$

$$ A_n=A^{'}_n-(A^{'}_1 \cup ... \cup A^{'}_{n-1})$$  why?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean (starting from $A_1=A_1'$). Why: double inclusion, if you wish, or drawing the case n=3.

Comment: for n=3 the 1st one is $$ A_3=(A^{'}_1\cup A^{'}_2\cup A^{'}_3)-(A^{'}_3\cup A^{'}_{2})$$
the 2nd one is 

$$ A_3=A^{'}_3-(A^{'}_1 \cup A^{'}_{2})$$ are both equivalent ?

Comment: Aaahh... typo! One should define $(A_n)$ by $A_1=A_1'$ and $$ A_n=(A^{'}_1\cup ...\cup A^{'}_n)-(A^{'}_1 \cup ... \cup A^{'}_{n-1}).$$ Then my previous comments apply. Sorry to have missed that. Are you sure Rudin uses your formula?

Comment: Yes. I am so confused. Page 307 of Rudin Principles of mathematical analysis. thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

At least in some editions of the book (say, the 3rd edition) there seems to be a typo. The defining identity $$ A_n=(A^{'}_1\cup ...\cup A^{'}_n)-(A^{'}_n \cup ... \cup A^{'}_{n-1})$$  should be replaced by $$ A_n=(A^{'}_1\cup ...\cup A^{'}_n)-(A^{'}_1 \cup ... \cup A^{'}_{n-1}).$$ Since $A_1=A^{'}_1$, this is equivalent to $$ A_n=A^{'}_n-(A^{'}_1 \cup ... \cup A^{'}_{n-1}).$$ Each definition leads to $$A_1\cup ...\cup A_n=A^{'}_1\cup ...\cup A^{'}_n,$$ for every $n$, and the rest follows.

Comment: many thanks for your kindly help !